# Generate equidistant points on a sphere [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

I want to generate equidistant points on a sphere (surface of the sphere). I have come up with this code.

```
n = 30; % number of points
r = 10; % radius of the sphere

thetha = 0:pi/(n/2):2*pi; 
phi    = -pi:2*pi/n:pi;
xp     = r.*sin(phi).*cos(thetha);
yp     = r.*sin(thetha).*sin(phi);
zp     = r.*cos(phi);
figure;plot3(xp,yp,zp,'*')
```

But this is what I get [image]

Can anyone tell where what mistake I am making in my code?

Answer (score 3):

You're only generating one path: a figure eight combination of a single closed circle in the *x*-*y* plane with single cosine along the *z*.

[image: Three Views of the single, closed curve]

To get a full sphere shape, permutations of the two paths must be taken.  This can be accomplished with `meshgrid`:

```
[t,p] = meshgrid(thetha,phi);    
xp    = r.*sin(p).*cos(t);
yp    = r.*sin(t).*sin(p);
zp    = r.*cos(p);  
plot3(xp,yp,zp,'-*');
grid('on');
box('on');
axis('square');
```

[image: Spherical shape plot]

Comment: Thank you. But this seems to generate more points than required. It is generating nxn points. But I need to generate n points only.

Comment: @nashynash Then have `thetha` and `phi` be of length `sqrt(n)` and flatten the arrays generated by `meshgrid`: `t = t(:); p = p(:);`.

Comment: I am sorry. I do not quite understand what you mean. Does it mean `thetha     = 0:pi/(sqrt(n)/2):sqrt(n);`  and `-sqrt(n):4*pi/sqrt(n):sqrt(n);`.

Comment: @nashynash No.  I mean that `meshgrid` will return `m`-by-`m` matrices if the inputs are vectors of length `m`.  So if you want `m` points, the input vectors must by of length `sqrt(m)`.  **Note:** The way you are making `thetha` and `phi` now creates vectors of length `n+1`; this is perfectly okay but must be understood.  Setting `n = 4` will make `thetha` and `phi` vectors of length `5`, `meshgrid` will generate `5`-by-`5` matrices, and `t = t(:); p = p(:);` will make them vectors of length `25`.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but I am not able to get 30 equidistant points. Instead, I get 36 points. I set `theta` and `phi` as `thetha     = 0:pi/sqrt(n):pi; ` `phi        = -pi:2*pi/sqrt(n):pi;`.

Comment: @nashynash I understand your goal now.  And from doing a little research, it is apparently [not possible](https://www.maths.unsw.edu.au/about/distributing-points-sphere) to distribute 30 points equidistantly on a sphere without some serious effort and definitions. My answer above will generate a spheroidal shape but will not generate the desired set of points.  And, unfortunately, I do not have enough technical knowledge in the area to write such a function at this moment.

Comment: Ah! Well, that clarifies a lot of things. Anyhow, thank you for your time and effort.